# Remove expo vector icons from RN Project(Expo Bare Workflow)

Tags: react-native, expo, apple-appclips

Using Expo Bare Workflow

Expo SDK Version: 40.0.1
Platform: iOS

We are trying to build an iOS AppClip which has a size constraint of 10MB.

While creating the IPA file we see expo vector icons are packaged along, which is increasing the size by around 4MB which is making a big impact on the size constraint. We want to exclude these assets specific to expo vector icons from the final binary. We are now stuck here to figure out a way to exclude these and cut down the size, any help from the community is highly appreciated!